# Txt to XML Python parser

Tags: python

I tried to parse a .txt file that looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compare Results
Compare Directory 1 : /data/Run_288/bitmaps
Compare Directory 2 : /data/Run_301/bitmaps
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 idx, Filename                                                         ,   Exact,    F3x3,    F5x5,    F7x7, Threshold,    P/F
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1, ASCII_APPE_600X450_150_colorManBasic2.blackGrayReproductionImage_0_2p_color_test_four_object.pdf_20190522005734_00001.tif,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,    PASS
   2, ASCII_APPE_600X450_150_colorManBasic2.blackGrayReproductionImage_0_2p_color_test_four_object.pdf_20190522005734_00002.tif,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,    PASS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bitmap Compare FAILURE !!! Threshold Exceeded : Threshold Values : Exact = 0 : Fuzzy 3x3 = 200 : Fuzzy 5x5 = 100 : Fuzzy 7x7 = 50 : Threshold 7x7 = 0
3, MIME_Test3_Job_setup__600X600_50_default_default_PPST56_003.mjm_20190521213826_00001.tif,    2083,    1180,     650,     262,      52,    FAIL

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to obtain an xml with this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Suite date="2019-05-27T10:47:03" compareDir1="/data/Run_288/bitmaps" compareDir2="/data/Run_301/bitmaps">
<Test name="ASCII_APPE_600X450_150_colorManBasic2.blackGrayReproductionImage_0_2p_color_test_four_object.pdf_20190522005734_00001.tif" result="pass">
</Test>
<Test name="ASCII_APPE_600X450_150_colorManBasic2.blackGrayReproductionImage_0_2p_color_test_four_object.pdf_20190522005734_00002.tif" result="pass">
</Test>
<Test name="MIME_Test3_Job_setup__600X600_50_default_default_PPST56_003.mjm_20190521213826_00001.tif" result="crash">
</Test>
</Suite>
```

This is the code that should do the work.The problem is that is not working and with my little python knowledge I don't know why.Can somebody help me please with this?!
Thank you!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element('Suite')
with open('file3.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    print(lines)
#add first subelement
celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'Test')
import itertools as it
#for every line in input file
#group consecutive dedup to one
for line in it.groupby(lines):
    line=line[0]
    #if its a break of subelements  - that is an empty space
    if not line:
        #add the next subelement and get it as celldata
        celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'test')
    else:
        #otherwise, split with : to get the tag name
        tag = line.split(",")
        #format tag name
        el=ET.SubElement(celldata,tag[1])
        print(tag[1])
        print(tag[7])
        tag=' '.join(tag[1]).strip()
      if 'PASS' in line:
           tag = line.split(",")[-1].strip()
      elif 'FAILURE' in line:
           splist =  filter(None,line.split(" "))
           tag = splist[splist.index(',')+1]

        el.text = tag

#prettify xml
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
formatedXML = minidom.parseString(
                          ET.tostring(
                                      root)).toprettyxml(indent=" ",encoding='utf-8').strip()
# Display for debugging
print formatedXML

#write the formatedXML to file.
with open("results.xml","w+") as f:
    f.write(formatedXML)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I would use regular expressions. My take:

```
data = '''-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compare Results
Compare Directory 1 : /data/Run_288/bitmaps
Compare Directory 2 : /data/Run_301/bitmaps
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 idx, Filename                                                         ,   Exact,    F3x3,    F5x5,    F7x7, Threshold,    P/F
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1, ASCII_APPE_600X450_150_colorManBasic2.blackGrayReproductionImage_0_2p_color_test_four_object.pdf_20190522005734_00001.tif,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,    PASS
   2, ASCII_APPE_600X450_150_colorManBasic2.blackGrayReproductionImage_0_2p_color_test_four_object.pdf_20190522005734_00002.tif,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,    PASS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bitmap Compare FAILURE !!! Threshold Exceeded : Threshold Values : Exact = 0 : Fuzzy 3x3 = 200 : Fuzzy 5x5 = 100 : Fuzzy 7x7 = 50 : Threshold 7x7 = 0
3, MIME_Test3_Job_setup__600X600_50_default_default_PPST56_003.mjm_20190521213826_00001.tif,    2083,    1180,     650,     262,      52,    FAIL

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'''

import re

dirs = []
for d in re.findall('Compare Directory\s+(\d+)\s*:\s*(.*?)$', data, flags=re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE):
    dirs += [d]

passes = []
fails = []

for line in data.split('\n'):
    for p in re.findall('(\d+,\s+(.*?),.*?PASS)$', line):
        passes += [p]
    for f in re.findall('(\d+,\s+(.*?),.*?FAIL)$', line):
        fails += [f]

s = f'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Suite date="2019-05-27T10:47:03" compareDir1="{dirs[0][1]}" compareDir2="{dirs[1][1]}">
'''

for p in passes:
    s += f'''   <Test name="{p[1]}" result="pass">
    </Test>
'''

for fail in fails:
    s += f'''   <Test name="{fail[1]}" result="crash">
    </Test>
'''

s += '''</Suite>'''

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Suite date="2019-05-27T10:47:03" compareDir1="/data/Run_288/bitmaps" compareDir2="/data/Run_301/bitmaps">
    <Test name="ASCII_APPE_600X450_150_colorManBasic2.blackGrayReproductionImage_0_2p_color_test_four_object.pdf_20190522005734_00001.tif" result="pass">
    </Test>
    <Test name="ASCII_APPE_600X450_150_colorManBasic2.blackGrayReproductionImage_0_2p_color_test_four_object.pdf_20190522005734_00002.tif" result="pass">
    </Test>
    <Test name="MIME_Test3_Job_setup__600X600_50_default_default_PPST56_003.mjm_20190521213826_00001.tif" result="crash">
    </Test>
</Suite>
```

Comment: When I run the script with ./parser3.py I'v got the following error: File "./parser3.py", line 40
    '''
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @corny Do you use Python2 or Python3 - in my script I use python f-strings, so python3 is needed.

Comment: I use Python 2.7.14

Comment: @corny Then you need to substitute the f-strings with `format()` calls for example.

Comment: Hey Andrej, thank you for the great help...I tried with format like this:  s += format('''<Test name="{p[1]}" result="pass">
    </Test>''') but the variable {p[1]} appears has it is like string instead of the name of the test(ASCII_APPE_600X450_150_colorManBasic2.blackGrayReproductionImage_0_2p_color_test_four_object.pdf_20190522005734_00001.tif).Second thing is how to "read" the data from external .txt file.I tried like follow but doesn't work :[with open('file3.txt') as f:
data = f.read()]

Comment: @corny Try this `s += '<Test name="' + p[1] + '" result="pass"></Test>'`